# What do we know about $2^p\ mod \ p^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I wonder what we do know about $2^p\ mod \ p^2\\$ where $p$ is a prime?

I know $2^p\equiv\ r*p+2\mod \ p^2$. Do we know anything about $r$?

Comment: The values of $r$ are given by a sequence in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: http://oeis.org/A179077 . There's no indication there that anything is known.

Comment: See [Fermat quotient.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient) and [$p-$derivation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-derivation)